# Binding to Selected Combo Box value that's converted

Tags: c#, xaml

I projected my enum to a combo box. But Now I want to bind to a selecteditem but unsure what the type is.

xaml side:

```
<ObjectDataProvider x:Key="MyEnumDataProvider" MethodName="GetValues" ObjectType="{x:Type System:Enum}">
    <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
        <x:Type TypeName="model:ContactMethod+Channels"></x:Type>
    </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
</ObjectDataProvider>

<ComboBox  ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource MyEnumDataProvider}}" SelectedItem="ContactType" Width="100"></ComboBox>
```

ContactMethod.cs

```
public enum Channels { Phone, Website, Email, Skype, Cell, Fax }
```

MVVM side:

this is where I have my trouble, Do I have to convert the "Object" selected or is there an easy way around this.

public ***_*_** ContactType {get; set;}

What goes in the underline?

Answer (score 0):

SelectedItem will be of type Channels

```
public Channels ContactType {get; set;}
```

and you will need to bind to property in Xaml like this

```
<ComboBox  ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource MyEnumDataProvider}}" SelectedItem="{Binding ContactType, Mode=TwoWay}" Width="100"></ComboBox>
```